# Hibernate : many to many linker table, best OO design

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

If I have 3 tables, with the expected normal columns :  **Customer**, **CustomerProductLinker** and **Product**.

And I want in my Java code to do this :

```
Customer customer =  myService.getCustomer(id); //calls hibernate session
List<Product> customerProducts = customer.getProducts();
```

What would my 3 entities look like and the respective collections within each, specifically the `getProducts()` method ? Or is it better to use **HQL** and a **named query** for this ?

I am creating the databse tables from the java code (using the create option in hibernate conf), so the table desgin can be altered if preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `@ManyToMany` relationship using `@JoinTable`. A customer has a set (or a list) of products. A product has a set (or a list) of customers.

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @ManyToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="customer_product",
               joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="customer_id")},
               inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="product_id")})
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>();
    ...

@Entity
public class Product {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="customer_product",
               joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="product_id")},
               inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="customer_id")})
    private Set<Customer> customers = new HashSet<Customer>();
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set up the entities like wannik suggested. Try to keep it simple. If you start using named queries you are doing more work and you are just covering an specific case.